# signal handler showing confusion in C

Tags: c, multiprocessing, signals

I am trying to use signal to sync N processes then print out something.
Each child process register a handler which print "yo" and "hihi" when catching SIGUSR1.
I use kill(0, SIGUSR1) to trigger every process. Since the default action for catching SIGUSR1 is being killed, I set a do-nothing handler for the main process so that it will wait all child died.

The fork and send signal program will repeat for k times, I expect it will show out N*k times "yo" and "hihi". However, it doesn't show enough "yo" and "hihi" as I expect. The number of "yo" is different every execution.

Here is my code, and thanks for your help!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define N 3 
    int pid_id[N];

    void handler2 (int signum)
    {
        printf("hihi\n");
    }

    void handler (int signum)
    {
        signal(SIGUSR2, handler2); 
        printf("yo\n");
        raise(SIGUSR2);
    }

    void handler_do_nothing (int signum)
    {
        ;
    }

    void child(int process_index)
    {
        struct sigaction sa;

        /* Register */
        memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
        sa.sa_handler = handler;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

        printf("I am %d.\n", getpid());
        pid_id[process_index] = getpid();
        sleep(1);

        exit(0);
    }

    int main()
    {
        int i, k, status;
        pid_t pid[N];
        pid_t pid_wait;

        struct sigaction sa_main;

        /* Register */    /* Main process will terminate if catch SIGUSR1 by default setting*/ 
        memset(&sa_main, 0, sizeof(sa_main));
        sa_main.sa_handler = handler_do_nothing;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa_main, NULL);

        /* Race k times */
        for (k=0;k<3;k++) 
        {

            for (i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                pid[i] = fork();
                if (pid[i]==0)
                {
                    child(i);
                }
            }

             // sleep();
             kill(0, SIGUSR1);

            for (i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    pid_wait = waitpid(pid[i], &status, WNOHANG);
                    printf("I am waiting..\n");
                    sleep(1);
                }while(pid_wait != pid[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("all done\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: For a start printf is not async safe, so you can't use it in a signal handler... See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child processes are being signalled before they have had time (i.e. execution resource scheduled) to install the new signal handler.

This means that when the main program sends `SIGUSR1`, some subset of the child processes will still have `handler_do_nothing` installed.

If you want to wait until the child processes have all finished setting up, you will need to add some interprocess communication mechanism - e.g. the children could signal the parent process when they are ready.

Comment: I don't understand why the child process will do handler_do_nothing..? In child process, I have registered handler..?

Comment: @KennyYang the main process runs in parallel with the child process, so it can get to `kill` before the child process gets to `sigaction`.